# Showing credit card for international flight purchased with online travel agency

Tags: delta-air-lines, expedia, payment-verifications

I recently purchased a ticket for my friend to fly from Argentina to the US. He will be flying with Delta. I am concerned that he will be asked to show my credit card at the check-in desk, but he does not have it.

I know Delta frequently asks to see credit cards, but I purchased the ticket via Expedia, so I don't think they will do so, seeing that they will not be charged if it were to be a fraud.

Does anyone have additional knowledge about this?

Comment: I experienced the same thing today and I was surprise, I gave my credit card to my son who bought the ticket for me, I was traveling to Burkina Faso and was told that without showing it, I could not board Delta. The cost of the ticket was already taken from my bank account and I was not aware of the practice. Thank you for sharing, I can see that I am not alone.

Answer (score 27):

Yes. I do have knowledge about this since I fly Delta internationally a lot from the USA to Ghana and Delta always requests you show credit card for locations like Ghana with reputations for fraud.

If you buy it from the Delta website, it alerts you about the requirement and you have to click a check box in agreement before you can purchase the ticket so you're aware.

If you bought it from Expedia however, it's Expedia that makes the payment to Delta and thus you're exempt from having to show the physical card.

If you're still uncomfortable after my explanation, you can also go to a Delta office any day before the persons flight and show the card. I did that when I purchased tickets for others directly from the Delta website.

Comment: [It appears that this Delta policy is specific to Africa](http://thepointsguy.com/2016/09/tip-flying-delta-to-africa-remember-credit-card/). I haven't seen any evidence that it applies to Argentina (it's possible that they do, but I haven't heard of it.)

Comment: It's listed on their US policy page too (click "Credit/Debit Card Presentation"), which supports Paul's suggestion of showing the card at a Delta office: http://www.delta.com/content/www/en_US/traveling-with-us/planning-a-trip/booking-information/online-booking.html#cc