# EgyptAir asking for creditcard of person who booked tickets

Tags: air-travel, usa, india, airlines, check-in

Recently I booked tickets for my in-law via Expedia. I got a deal from EgyptAir for Mumbai-NYC. After booking we realized that EgyptAir mentions on the confirmed ticket that a cardholder paying for the ticket must be one of the travelers in this booking and if fails to present card then they hold rights to deny boarding.

Do you have any advice on how to deal with this situation?

Comment: Try this solution. I've used it before. https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/86934/showing-credit-card-for-international-flight-purchased-with-online-travel-agency/86936#86936

Comment: This was the norm few years ago in Indian domestic flights. Furnishing photocopy of the card was OK with the airlines - by scratching out the CVV and/or Valid From/Thru dates on the card

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They allow you to send in via email a picture/scan of the credit card plus a signed authorization form if the owner of the card is not traveling. Call EgyptAir and get the email address for the customer service section to send the scan/form to.