# Non credit card holder travelling turkey

Tags: planning, payment-verifications

I am an Indian who has booked my flight tickets from someone else credit card from Turkish Airlines which travels from Istanbul to other city in Turkey. Will there be problem since I am not the credit card holder?

Comment: See http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/86934/showing-credit-card-for-international-flight-purchased-with-online-travel-agency/86936#86936